# custom node template (content type) is not working on drupal 7

Tags: drupal, themes

After applying following code into template.php, custom node template is not working on Drupal 7. For example, node--article.tpl.php

```
function jstheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
// If the content type's machine name is "my_machine_name" the file
// name will be "page--my-machine-name.tpl.php".
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' .    $variables['node']->type;
  } 
}
```

If I remove above code, node--article.tpl.php is picking up but not page--article.tpl.php

I assume that it should pick up page--article.tpl.php then node--article.tpl.php if they exist. Is this assumption wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code and your assumption is right. I tried using the above code in my local it worked fine, as a result it took `page--article.tpl.php` as page tpl and for node tpl it took `node--article.tpl.php`.

Steps to check:

1. hook_preprocess_page written in template.php will always take the priority.

Comment: I thought Drupal should pick up page-article.tpl.php and node-article.tpl.php as well if they exist both. Based on your answer it seems like Drupal will pick up only one of them even if they exist both?

Comment: yeah it will take both the tpl one will be custom page.tpl and custom node tpl.

Comment: ok but my drupal isn't worked like that. do you have any clue? in template.php file it has only above function.

Comment: In your page--article.tpl.php file This variable should be `$page['content']`, which inturns calls your custom node tpl. I would suggest you to copy all the contents form the page.tpl of bartick and paste it in your custom tpl file and the same applies for the custom node tpl too(bartick node.tpl => custom node tpl). Do some change and see wheater the changes are taking place.

Comment: Yes. I just used "  <?php   $body = field_get_items('node',$node, 'body');
  print $body[0]['value']; ?> ". Thank you!